# If x and y are two consecutive positive integer then how can we prove that $y^y>x^x$?

Tags: exponential-function, real-numbers

Actually we can prove it by just choosing random consecutive positive integers, but I want to know how we can prove it mathematically.

Comment: Many people consider the use of all-caps to be shouting, and therefore rude.

Comment: You should specifically say that y= x+ 1.  x= 2 and y= 1 are two consecutive integers for which this is not true!

Comment: @lulu what is all-caps please tell me if it seems that I'm rude then I will edit the post

Comment: You wrote your post using all capital letters.  That's what "all caps" means.

Comment: @lulu but if I write it in small letters then I'm not able to post the question

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $y>x >0$.

Claim: $y^y > y^x$. $y^y - y^x = y^{y-x}(y^x - 1)$. Then $y^x > 1^x = 1$, so $(y^x -1) > 0$, so $y^{y-x}(y^x -1 ) > 0$. So the claim holds.

Claim: $y^x > x^x$. We have $y>x$, so $y^2 > yx > x^2$, proceeding inductively gives $y^x>x^x$.

Putting the two together gives the desired result.

Comment: $0^0$ is NOT equal to 1.  It is "undefined".

Comment: Alright, sure. Doesn't matter really. In any case, we don't want $x=0$.

Comment: Hey guys please read the question carefully the question tells that x and y are positive integers it doesn't tells that x and y are non-negative.so we can't include 0

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = x^x,$ then $f'(x) = f(x)\cdot(\log(x)+1).$

$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^+. f'(x) > 0 \implies \forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^+. f(x) \text{ is strictly increasing.}$